# LabVIEW: Plotting to Waveform Graph causes memory leak

Tags: labview

I am trying to plot image data to the wave form graph and I'm seeing memory leak. The leak doesn't seem to come from the .NET layer but comes from LabVIEW.

I have such block diagram as below and with this implementation there is a leakage. The memory gets full eventually and the system hangs.

[image]
[https://yoshidad-gmail.tinytake.com/sf/MjU3Njk1M183NzUyNzI0](http://This%20is%20far%20more%20interesting%20to%20see%20it.%20https://yoshidad-gmail.tinytake.com/sf/MjU3Njk1M183NzUyNzI0)

If I don't connect the image data (RawImageData) to the graph then there is no leak.

[image]

I am puzzled as to why this is happening ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might try writing an empty array to the graph immediately before writing the data every time. It may appear to stutter in this case but I would be curious to know if it stops the leak.

Comment: Another debug, what if you move the the waveform graph reference out of the while loop. Second step could be to connect your graph property to the graph (not dynamically referenced), and what if you write to the terminal of WFGraph? This is something that NI will be very interested in. Or what if you write another dataset to the graph? Or use an ['always copy'](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/glang/always_copy/) node between the .net and LabVIEW property node?

Comment: When it comes to refnums in LabVIEW, anything that doesn't have to be inside a loop SHOULD NOT BE inside a loop. Refnums account for a huge number of LabVIEW memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try closing your references, specifically the `Frame` reference. The way LabVIEW handles images is a little strange and they can act a bit more like actual memory (c/c++) refs than your typical LabVIEW ref.

It's a hunch, but the `Frame` might be held in memory until the reference is closed, especially since the data from the frame is being used by the `WFGraph`.